# Ajaxplorer - Remove powered by Ajaxplorer

Tags: php, file-manager, pydio

I am using [Ajaxplorer](http://ajaxplorer.info) 4.0.4 Version. i want to remove "Powered by Ajaxplorer , written by charles" etc.

How can i remove this and set my custom message, \
 I am willing to pay for this.

Comment: Your best bet is to use the forum on their site and ask there.

Comment: not very nice to remove such hints from free tools, especially without asking the original programmers

Comment: Their license specifically denies you the right to do that, thus violating their license and stealing great quality free software. Don't do it. http://ajaxplorer.info/features/services/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

technically: search the source code for the string, remove it.

but, **please don't do this!**
the developers released this under the AGPL Licence, see http://ajaxplorer.info/community/faq/

> **Can I use AjaXplorer freely on my website, even if I’m a company**
>
> As long as you do not modify AjaXplorer deeply (modifications like
>   theming or little tweaks are not taken into account), and as long as
>   you leave a link to the source code (i.e. to this website, except if
>   you want to host the source code on your own website) on the
>   user-interface (this is the particularity of AGPL against GPL), yes
>   you can.  For example, if you change the logo of the splashscreen
>   (using the gui.ajax plugin options) and let the « Powered by
>   AjaXplorer » mention, this will be ok. If you want to remove this
>   reference, you should contact us.

Answer (score -1):

Load the whole codebase into an IDE, search the whole thing for the string "Powered by Ajaxplorer , written by charles", then replace it with whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Not a good practice for AGPL open source software.  Plus it would likely get overwritten again anyway on the next update.